# ERROR: Could not build wheels for opencv-contrib-python which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, pip

pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel then ran this with a version specified: pip install -U opencv-python==4.5.5.62

Iam getting following errors.. How to proceed ? Thank you in advance.

Processing e:\tensorflow\models\research
Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [25 lines of output]
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools_importlib.py:23: UserWarning: `importlib-metadata` version is incompatible with `setuptools`.
This problem is likely to be solved by installing an updated version of `importlib-metadata`.
warnings.warn(msg)  # Ensure a descriptive message is shown.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 36, in 
File "", line 14, in 
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools_*init*_.py", line 18, in 
from setuptools.dist import Distribution
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 35, in 
from .*importlib import metadata
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools_importlib.py", line 39, in 
disable_importlib_metadata_finder(metadata)
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools_importlib.py", line 12, in disable_importlib_metadata_finder
import importlib_metadata
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\importlib_metadata_*init**.py", line 466, in 
**version** = version(**name**)
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\importlib_metadata_*init*_.py", line 433, in version
return distribution(package).version
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\importlib_metadata_*init*_.py", line 406, in distribution
return Distribution.from_name(package)
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\importlib_metadata_*init*_.py", line 175, in from_name
dists = resolver(name)
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools_vendor\importlib_metadata_*init*_.py", line 886, in find_distributions
found = self._search_paths(context.name, context.path)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'name'
[end of output]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.

Answer (score 0):

This versions and commands solved the issue.

`pip install setuptools==60.8.2`

`pip install -U opencv-python==4.5.5.62`

`python -m pip install --user --upgrade pip`

`python -m pip install`